# Select Array not being sent via $_POST

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, html-select

Here is a small section of my form. It is set up that a user can add information about one munro, or multiple. Hence the use of arrays for input boxes, check boxes and select option boxes.

```
<fieldset class="row1">
        <H2>Munro Details</H2>

        <table id="munroTable" class="form" border="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" required="required" name="chk[]" checked="checked" /></td>
                    <td>
                        <label>Name</label>
                        <input class = "textbox"  type="text" maxlength = "30" required="required" name="name[]">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label>Height (metres)</label>
                        <input class = "textbox"  type="number" maxlength = "5" required="required" name="height[]">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label>Classification</label>
                        <select name = "classification[]">
                            <optgroup label="Scottish Hills">
                                <option value="Munro">Munro</option>
                                <option value="Corbett">Corbett</option>
                                <option value="Graham">Graham</option>
                                <option value="Donald">Donald</option>
                            </optgroup>
                            <optgroup label="Non Scottish Hills">
                                <option value="Furth">Furth</option>
                                <option value="Hewitt">Hewitt</option>
                                <option value="Wainwright">Wainwright</option>
                                <option value="Brikett">Brikett</option>
                            </optgroup>
                            <optgroup label="UK wide">
                                <option value="Marilyn">Marilyn</option>
                            </optgroup>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label>Topped?</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" value = "Yes" name="topped[]" checked="checked"> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <p> 
            <input class = "myButton" type="button" value="Add Munro" onClick="addRow('munroTable')" /> 
            <input class = "myButton" type="button" value="Remove Munro" onClick="deleteRow('munroTable')"  />  
        </p>
    </fieldset>
```

The issue I'm having is with the select option for "classification".

When I use `echo "<br>All data".print_r($_POST);` so see what data is being sent sucessfully, the classification doesn't show up.

I'm assuming it is something very simple, but I just can't find it.

Thanks for taking the time to look.

Comment: Think remove the white/blank space from `classification` name from `name = "classification[]"` to `name="classification[]"`

Comment: Do what @mageDev0688 said for all the other times you've done this in your HTML attributes too.

Comment: Do you even have `form` tag in your HTML? Do you even send POST request? Do you even send any request?

Comment: Perfect. Thank you gentlemen/ladies. Knew it would be something simple.

Comment: So what's the solution?